# How to treat result of vaddv_u8 in arm64 as a neon register

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon, arm64

`vaddv_u8` and some other similar new v-intrinsics from AArch64 (arm64) return `uint8_t`. How can I treat result of this intrinsic as a neon register instead of plain C type?

[For example](https://godbolt.org/g/vgS6Zm):

```
void paddClz(uint8_t* x)
{
    uint8x8_t ret = vdup_n_u8(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i, x += 8)
    {
        uint8x8_t x8 = vld1_u8(x);
        uint8_t sum = vaddv_u8(x8);
        uint8x8_t r = vdup_n_u8(sum); //or: r = vset_lane_u8(sum, r, 0);
        r = vclz_u8(r);
        ret = vext_u8(ret, r, 1);
    }
    vst1_u8(x, ret);
}
```

what clang generated:

```
paddClz(unsigned char*): // @paddClz(unsigned char*)
  mov x8, xzr
  movi d0, #0000000000000000
.LBB0_1: // =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  ldr d1, [x0, x8]
  add x8, x8, #8 // =8
  cmp w8, #64 // =64
  addv b1, v1.8b
  dup v1.8b, v1.b[0]   <<== useless! I only need/use/care about v1.b[0]
  clz v1.8b, v1.8b
  ext v0.8b, v0.8b, v1.8b, #1
  b.ne .LBB0_1
  str d0, [x0, #64]
  ret
```

As you can see there is a useless `dup` intrinsic required to get the `uint8_t vaddv_u8` result converted to a type that will work as an argument for `vclz_u8`.  I take only first lane from the subsequent `vclz_u8` result, so actually duplicating it to all lanes would be wasted work.

How can I write it in intrinsics to get that `sum` in neon typed variable without making the compiler emit useless opcodes?  (And preferably without this extra noise in the source code.) To make it clear and obvious if it wasn't: I'm not asking to optimize or improve that piece of code that I posted; I simply wrote it to show the issue.

Comment: Don't count on being able to get current compilers to emit non-terrible asm for ARM intrinsics.  For some reason they're much worse with ARM SIMD than with x86 SSE/AVX intrinsics, or PowerPC Altivec intrinsics.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, totally agree, but in this case for some reason intrinsic itself is declared in a way that makes you go through some hops to get simplest and most straightforward code where you have to rely that compiler is smart enough, while there was no need for such requirement in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes GCC lags way behind LLVM in this department. LLVM (at least the ARMv8 version shipped with XCode) does an excellent job of emitting ARM SIMD instructions from intrinsics.

Comment: @BitBank: Thanks, I'll have to try `clang -target aarch64` on https://godbolt.org/ next time I'm looking at ARM intrinsics.  (I only mess around with ARM code for SO answers.)

Comment: Looks like arm64 isn't as well implemented in general (so far). I'd be interested to try on armcc (arm's compiler).

Answer (score 2):

You should really get a test device with an in-order SoC. Apple's A series chips are all out-of-order, by far the most powerful ones to be precise.

Your implementation might run adequately fast on your iPhone, but will be barely any faster than the simplest C versions on in-order cores, straight unusable.

Think twice before you rush into writing loops on NEON.
You can avoid the so-called "horizontal" operations altogether most of the time by transposing the matrix, then do the "vertical" math instead.

---

```
#define vuzp8(a, b, c) ({ \
    c = vuzp_u8(a, b); \
    a = c.val[0]; \
    b = c.val[1]; \
})

void foo(uint8_t *pDst, uint8_t *pSrc)
{
    uint8x8x4_t top, bottom;
    uint8x8x2_t temp;

    top = vld4_u8(pSrc);
    pSrc += 32;
    bottom = vld4_u8(pSrc);

    vuzp8(top.val[0], bottom.val[0], temp);
    vuzp8(top.val[1], bottom.val[1], temp);
    vuzp8(top.val[2], bottom.val[2], temp);
    vuzp8(top.val[3], bottom.val[3], temp);

    top.val[0] += bottom.val[0];
    top.val[1] += bottom.val[1];
    top.val[2] += bottom.val[2];
    top.val[3] += bottom.val[3];

    top.val[0] += top.val[1];
    top.val[2] += top.val[3];

    top.val[0] += top.val[2];

    top.val[0] = vclz_u8(top.val[0]);

    vst1_u8(pDst, top.val[0]);
}
```

---

Another example where you ask yourself if `intrinsux` makes sense at all. Its clumsiness makes the code much more complex, and it isn't expressive enough to do three 128bit plus one 64bit adds instead of six 64bit ones.

In addition, you have to double check if the compiler didn't mess up anything, again, especially when you do permutations(`vzip, vuzp, vtrn`)

I think the machine code will be fine on `aarch32`, but I'm not so sure about `aarch64` where the permutation instructions are vastly different.

I think that you understand by now why I hate `intrinsux` like the pest. It's more nuisance than any help.

PS: The **Teclast P10** Android tablet is quite a good candidate as an `aarch64` test device: All the eight cores are the same, Android 7.12 64bit is installed, and it only costs around $100.

Comment: [@Bitbank says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028458/how-to-treat-result-of-vaddv-u8-in-arm64-as-a-neon-register/50060840#comment87123343_50028458) clang for AArch64 is non-terrible with intrinsics.  Have you tried it recently?  Also that there isn't a large penalty anymore for NEON<->integer on ARMv8.  Is that just Apple's ARMv8 cores, or is that AArch64 in general?

Comment: @PeterCordes I dunno, to be honest. I, too have no in-order ARMv8 device yet ;-) (but soon) As you can see above, transposing matrices is a trivial thing on NEON, and thus, I rarely do any horizontal math. And besides, the destination operand of horizontal instructions on `aarch64` isn't an ARM register. When you write in assembly, the result lands in index zero of a vector. It cannot be expressed in `intrinsux` though which is outrageous. `intrinsux` badly needs a complete rehaul.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a ridiculous design.  Intel intrinics have some similar warts, [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39318496).  (Also mentions that it's hard to get `pmovzx` with a memory operand.)  But that's just omission of useful stuff, not wrong types.

Comment: @PeterCordes What really sucks is that `intrinsux` is fragmented between `aarch32` and `aarch64`. You cannot use the `aarch64` specific ones such as `trn1/2`, `zip1/2`, `uzp1/2` if you target `aarch32`. What's the point of `intrinsux` if you have to write separate codes for each architecture anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [I can do this in clang](https://godbolt.org/g/4CS1Ut):

```
int paddClz(const uint8_t* x)
{
    uint8x8_t x8 = vld1_u8(x);
    uint8_t sum = vaddv_u8(x8);
    uint8x8_t r;
    r = vset_lane_u8(sum, r, 0);
    r = vclz_u8(r);
    return vget_lane_u8(r, 0);
}
```

This produces exactly what I want:

```
addv b0, v0.8b
clz v0.8b, v0.8b
```

However, [gcc produces some mess](https://godbolt.org/g/68qDje) from that code. The other issue is that it uses uninitialized `r` and depending on how you setup your build it might not be acceptable. More over, it doesn't seem to work in more complex scenarios. Is there a better/proper way to do it?

Comment: You do eventually want the result in a scalar ARM register, so you could maybe write the source so the compiler can `addv` / `umov w0, v0.b[0]` / `clz w0, w0`.  But then you're counting the 24 leading zeros above the 8-bit value.  If ARM throughtput is better than NEON, it might still be a win to have to subtract 24, especially if you can fold that into something else for free.

Comment: In my case I need the result in neon and I keep processing/manipulating it there.

Comment: Then a function that returns `uint8x8_t` would be a better example than `int`, right?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's just to make some minimal example that compiles, not some actual code.

Comment: I mean an example of what you need / are trying to achieve.  Returning an `int` allows `clz w0,w0` as part of a possible optimal solution, but returning a `uint8x8_t` doesn't.  It's important to craft your compiler test-cases carefully if you want meaningful results.  e.g. maybe some compiler only shoots itself in the foot when you later ask for the value as an `int`.  Or maybe some compiler *only* gives good results for this when you later ask for an `int`, instead of using it with some further vector operations.  This doesn't prove that you can get clang to generate good code for using `r`.

Comment: Clang for x86 will figure out when the upper elements of a vector aren't inputs to any further instructions and will optimize away the zeroing of upper elements for `_mm_set_ss(my_float)`.  But if you use the vector as an input to something else, it might actually do the zeroing of upper elements.  [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39318496).  So your test doesn't prove that this works for what you actually want, just for getting an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround potentially makes the performance worse. Your problem is written as if you want a scalar result from your single vector of uint8_t's. There's nothing wrong with the vaddv_u8 instruction returning a scalar value. On ARMv8, the "NEON unit" is now fully integrated and doesn't have a large penalty for moving data between NEON and ARM registers. Just use the C intrinsic to count leading zeros of the result and you'll have what you need:

```
int paddClz(const uint8_t* x)
{
    uint8x8_t x8 = vld1_u8(x);
    uint8_t sum = vaddv_u8(x8);
    return __builtin_clz(sum) - 24;
}
```

The intrisic will get compiled into the single ARM instruction (CLZ).

**If you're working with a larger data set, then write the C code to properly reflect that fact.**

Comment: The OP [actually wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028458/how-to-treat-result-of-vaddv-u8-in-arm64-as-a-neon-register/50053428#comment87122827_50031818) to keep using further SIMD instructions on the result, but this is the right answer to the question as asked (except you're now counting the 24 leading zeros in an `int` before the low 8 bits, which is what `vclz_u8` counts).  The OP should fix the example code, like I commented on his answer.

Comment: Thanks for catching the 32/8 issue. He keeps creating misleading questions which appear to focus on a single NEON register. If he's really working with large data sets, then he''ll keep getting incorrect solutions.

Comment: Exactly.  Plus this question was a mess before I cleaned up the terminology to talk about intrinsics instead of opcodes!  It's an interesting question, so I wish it was asked correctly.

Comment: Please read the title of the question. That's the question,there were no other questions. The body of entire message just shows an example, not some code that I'm trying to optimize, in other words I don't care if somebody provides alternative piece of the code that does it 10 times faster. I simply want to know in general: "How to treat result of vaddv_u8 in arm64 as a neon register"

Comment: @Pavel - why are you fighting the instruction set? The addv instruction takes a NEON register and gives a scalar result. If you don't like that, you can do a series of pairwise adds or move the result from addv back into a NEON register.

Comment: I'm not fighting instruction set. I'm trying to do exactly what instruction set does, but for some strange reason they decided that it's better to return plain uintX_t from thse new intrinsics instead of neon vector type. OR... perhaps compilers didn't catch up yet and do not handle well these scalar results when you try to use them the way you'd use them in pure asm.

Comment: ok, so it sounds like you're fighting the compiler. Clang/LLVM will normally produce better results than GCC. If all else fails, write assembly language in a separate .S file. It's the only way to guarantee that your instructions don't get changed.

Comment: @BitBank: GNU C inline asm will reliably avoid your instructions getting changed, without the overhead of a function call.  It's not ideal because the optimizer still can't schedule them or understand what they do.

Comment: @Pavel: you have to realize that intrinsics are 1 step removed from asm instructions.  A `uint8x8_t` C variable is *not* a NEON register.  If the compiler wants to, it can spill it to memory, or optimize it away (e.g. treat the intrinsics like any other source code, and optimize the asm to different operations according to the as-if rule, with different intermediate values).  It looks like `vaddv_u8` is designed badly, but you have to realize that writing intrinsics is very different from writing asm directly.  Please keep this in mind when phrasing your questions.

Comment: Off course I understand that `uint8x8_t` is not guaranteed to be a register :) remove optimization settings and you won't see any neon at all. But for a simple case if compiler isn't completely broken I see no reason for it not to be a neon register. By the way, what does "are 1 step removed from asm instructions" mean?